# Can I use the setTimout() function on a parent window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, onsubmit

```
<form id="#add_new_contact_method" name="add_new_contact_method"
style="padding:10px;" onsubmit="parent.replaceAttributesForm();
closeModal();">
```

closeModal(): http://pastebin.com/M2Vz2TwV

I've got this form submitting, closing a modal, and running my replaceAttributesForm() function correctly. I can't seem to be able to use the setTimeout function with it without getting a TypeError: 'undefined' message.

Any thoughts on how to use parent.setTimeout(alert('Test'), 2000) and have it work?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to pass a function.  It doesn't matter which `setTimeout()` you call.

Comment: Looks more and more that the problem lies elsewhere. Look through the whole code again. Also you might want to enable [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), if you haven't already. It might help.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to call setTimeout on the parent window.

just use

```
setTimeout(function(){
    parent.window.someMethodInParent();
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a closure as first parameter of `setTimeout` function :

```
parent.setTimeout(function(){ alert('Test'); }, 2000);
```

Comment: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'alert('Test')')

Comment: Please try `parent.alert('Test');` instead of `alert('Test');`.

Comment: Radio silence. closeModal() seems to stop it...?

Comment: Can you add to your question the code of `closeModal` function.

Comment: Add it to your initial question. BTW, I see some `this.parent.location.reload(true);` instructions : if you kill (ie change location) your parent, all javascript call stack is cleared to.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` needs a function to run.

Writing `parent.setTimeout(alert('Test'), 2000)` you give it a value returned by alert to run.

You have to write:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Test');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'alert('Test')')

Comment: Works perfectly when pasted into Chrome's console.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are problems with using it in 'onsubmit' ?